# Finding the moments in which a mass moves through the equilibrium position

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, harmonics

I am having trouble understanding what one has to do when they are asked all the positions in which a mass is in a certain position:
The movement equation is $x = 3 \sin(600t + \pi/4)$.
Then I am asked when the mass goes through $x=0$,
So 
$0=\sin(600t+ \pi/4)$
But here is my problem, the next step is:
$600t+\pi/4= \pi k$

Why do you equal the equation to $\pi$? 
I need an answer not only to this case, but to any other problem where the position $x$ is not the equilibrium position.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Inverse ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A $\sin(a)=0$ if and only if $a$ is a multiple of $\pi$. If you don't believe me, just look at a graph. Thus, $0=\sin(600t+\pi/4)$ must imply $600t+\pi/4 = k\pi$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: Ok but when the sinus of the angle is different from zero, then what do you need to do?

Comment: Find all solutions to the equation $\sin(a)=b$ (where $b$ is your non-zero variable) on the interval $[0,2\pi)$. There may be one or two solutions, say $a_1$ and $a_2$. Then the solutions to $\sin(a)=b$ are $a_1+2\pi k$ and $a_2+2\pi k$ for all integers $k$.